# Python readlines() function writing [' and \n to file

Tags: python, readlines

So I have this code here which I am sure is trivial to my question as it is just question about readlines in general:

```
        lines = file_in.readlines()
        self.inputText.insert(1.0, lines,)
```

If I were to read in a text file, it would write like this to a text file

> ['Example Text'\n']

or something to that nature instead of what we really want which is:

> Example Text

How do I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3):

[`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) gives you a list of lines. When you try to turn a list as a string, it gives you brackets and commas and the `repr` (the for-a-programmer-representation, rather than the `str`, the for-an-end-user-representation, which is why you get the quotes and the `\n` instead of a newline) of each of its elements. That's not what you want.

You *could* fix it up after the fact, or add each of the lines one by one, but there's a much simpler way: just use [`read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read), which gives you the whole file as one big string:

```
contents = file_in.read()
self.inputText.insert(1.0, contents,)
```

On top of being less code, and harder to get wrong, this means you're not making Python waste time splitting the contents up into a bunch of separate lines just so you can put them back together.

---

As a side note, [there's almost *never* a good reason to call `readlines()`](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html).

Answer (score 0):

`readlines` returns a list of lines. To insert this into a text widget you can join those items with a newline, like so:

```
lines = file_in.readlines()
self.inputText.insert("1.0", "\n".join(lines))
```

Comment: I think you just want `"".join(lines)`, because `readlines()` doesn't strip the lines.